# Yii2. Generate ul list directly from SearchModel

Tags: sql, yii2

I need following output:

```
<ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#section1">Value 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2">Value 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3">Value 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section4">Value 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section5">Value 5</a></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

where Value is a data from a data base (DB) (value of some field for example). Is it possible to get recodrs from DB already inserted to some predefined string?

Comment: What do you mean by some predefined string? Maybe example, what you want to see.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are needing this. 
Use [ArrayHelper](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-arrayhelper.html) to create an array to store all the data from certain model.

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
$dataFromDBTable = ArrayHelper::map(ModelName::find()->all(), 'id', 'name');
?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($dataFromDBTable as $id => $name) { ?>
    <li><a href="#section<?=$id?>"><?=$name?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use [Html](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-html.html) to create list. Example:

```
<?=yii\helpers\Html::u($items, $options); ?>
```

Comment: Its not just `u` its `ul`

Answer (score 0):

I used ListView with 'tag' => false:

```
<?= 
ListView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'options' => ['tag' => false],
            'itemOptions' => ['tag' => false],
            'layout' => "\n{items}",
            'itemView' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
                          return $this->render('_specialization_li',['model' => $model, 'index' => $index]);
                          },
            ]);
?>
```

Inside _specialization_li I wrote:

```
<li><a href="#section<?= $model->id ?>"><?= $model->name_ ?></a></li>
```

Also there is a bugfix for 'tag'=>false on github:

https://github.com/pkirill99/yii2/commit/528b97183591376da80ee168a2a1132ea36f33cf